# produce graphs from table with months, days, years

Tags: php, mysql

I have never done this before so I am asking for the best way how to do it.

I have mysql table (this one is for simplification, honestly I have 3 tables and I make joins between them):

> ID, PRICE, TYPE, TIME_MILLIS

(time when inserted to db)

Now I would like to produce graphs with structured data, so if I want to produce monthly graph I need data ordered by months (Jan-Dec), if daily (1-31). So I think data should be somehow "grouped". And then I should be able to select between TYPEs as well.

I tried simple select for all data from db in preferred date range and then to group it with php foreach cycle but I think this is not optimal for a lot of lines in db (up to 1 000 000) and it is not computing power effective.

I just need to find best way how to write mysql select for this (not the right javascript graph engine).

Comment: use google graphs for this

Comment: You have to make 3 queries as per your requirement in which these queries will fetch day wise data, month wise data and year wise data. All the comparison made on your TIME_MILLI attribute. I dont know what exact output you need in your graph. It will be better if you post your table stuctures.

Answer (score 0):

I present you an easy boucle that dumps data for each month.
You can insert a WHERE statement to filter data from the TYPE table. I can't write the script because I don't know which is the structure of the table.

```
$months=array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July",
"August","September","October","November","December");

for ($m=0;$m<count($months);$m++){
    $month=$m+1;
$month_data=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as  total 
FROM file WHERE month(dia)='$month'",$conn);

$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($month_data);
echo "<br>Files in $months[$m] ".$data['total'];
}
```